# How to check programmatically is signature visible in PDF after load

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I sign PDF document using JSignPdf with visible signature. It’s very important to do it correctly so I want to do JUnit test which check is this signature (visible) exist. I wrote test which check has document got signature but I don’t know how to check has it got visible signature. Is possible to load document using e.g. iText and check it?

Comment: *"Is possible to load document using e.g. iText and check it?"* - Yes, cf. e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51063791/1729265).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [itext pdf verify if signature is visible or invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063791/itext-pdf-verify-if-signature-is-visible-or-invisible)